# Call method from specific Js version file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two version of datatable.js 1.9 and 1.10 and I have included both in a master page and child page.

Now for particular functionality I want to access method from 1.9 only,

I have used

```
jQuery.noConflict();
```

But it throws

> $ is not a function

While in sample app like jsfiddle I found this is working when having on both version in similar page.

What should be the case here

Comment: but why have you included both...its wrong

Comment: probably mistake while including jquery

Comment: want to have some new feature of latest, but found one feature is missing in new version

Answer (score 0):

Just use it like this:

```
var $i = jQuery.noConflict();
```

When you want a function call using the opject, use:

`$i.methodName();` instead of `$.methodName();`

Comment: I am doing similar, but it says $ is not a function for other jquery pligin

Comment: Use same method over the other one as well to prevent the conflict

Comment: I didn't understand